# ndk-build using amadillo (blas lapack) and vlfeat lib

Tags: android-ndk, lapack, blas, armadillo, vlfeat

I am trying to compile c++ code written using armadillo that I have uncomment blas lapack in config.hpp and also vlfeat (vl.so) in Andriod make file.

In Jni folder I have the following Andriod.mk

```html
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \libblas
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \liblapack
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \libvl



include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE+=mjni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES+=HelloJNI.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES+=featureExtraction.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=$(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+=$(LOCAL_PATH)/include/externalInclude/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+=$(LOCAL_PATH)/include/externalInclude/armadillo_bits


#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := blas lapack
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

for each module blas, lapack, and vlfeat I used .so libraries as follows:

```html
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libvl

MY_LIBRARY_NAME := libvl

### export include path
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include/vl
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include/src

### path to library
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libvl.so

### export dependency on the library
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS += -l$(MY_LIBRARY_NAME)

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and

```html
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libblas

MY_LIBRARY_NAME := libblas

### export include path
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../include/OpenBLAS/include

### path to library
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libblas.so

### export dependency on the library
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS += -l$(MY_LIBRARY_NAME)

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I have got the following errors when I use ndk-build command:

```html
jni/include/externalInclude/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:172: error: undefined reference to 'sdot_'
jni/include/externalInclude/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:98: error: undefined reference to 'ssyrk_'
jni/include/externalInclude/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:28: error: undefined reference to 'sgemv_'
jni/include/externalInclude/armadillo_bits/blas_wrapper.hpp:63: error: undefined reference to 'sgemm_'

 error: undefined reference to 'vl_sift_new'
 error: undefined reference to 'vl_sift_process_first_octave'
 error: undefined reference to 'vl_sift_delete'
 error: undefined reference to 'vl_sift_detect'
 error: undefined reference to 'vl_sift_calc_keypoint_orientations'
 error: undefined reference to 'vl_sift_calc_keypoint_descriptor'
 error: undefined reference to 'vl_sift_process_next_octave'
```

Comment: Have you found a way to fix the linking problem?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and after some struggleing i found a sulotion

1. go to http://danilogiulianelli.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/how-to-build-gcc-fortran-cross-compiler.html and build the gcc cross compiler . i did it for ndk-8d.

make sure that after running the script you can see the 2 folders that the script created in
android-ndk-r8d\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.8.0
android-ndk-r8b\android-ndk-r8d\toolchains\x86-4.8.

2. download blas lib and update the following field in blas make.in:
   instead of

   ```
   FORTRAN  = gfortran

   FORTRAN = $(yourPath)/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/x86-4.8.0/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/i686-linux-android-gfortran
   ```

run the makefile.

3. add in you android.mk and add the following localflags

   ```
   LOCAL_LDFLAGS           := $(OPT) $(PROF) -lblas -llapack -lstdc++ -lgfortran
   ```
4. run ndk-build

   - i had problem with ndk-8d that had missing files of  gcc 4.8, in order to solve it i copied the missing files from ndk-9 and it works.